# iptables redirect local cennections

Tags: centos, iptables, portforwarding

I used

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8085
```

to redirect all http requests to jboss server on port 8085. This works fine if packets come from outside.
If I try to open from the same machine it doesnt work. Telnet gives connection refused.

How do I redirect local connections?

Working on centos, kernel 2.6.18 x64

Answer (score 2):

local generated packets does not income on eth0.
you have to do this:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --src 0/0 --dst 127.0.0.1. -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8085
```

and

```
To redirect locally generated packets, you must have the kernel option CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_LOCAL set to Y
```

from: http://wiki.debian.org/Firewalls-local-port-redirection

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, it had the full explanation which helped me realize that things won't work if the kernel wasn't compiled with CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_LOCAL=y.

Answer (score 0):

Also to allow forward just run the command

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```